# initialize an array of std::byte with integer type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a

```
typedef std::array<std::byte, 4> CatType;
```

And I want to initialize a constant of this type. I can do

```
const CatType mycat = {std::byte{0x00}, std::byte{0x00}, std::byte{0x00}, std::byte{0x00}};
```

Which works, but I'd like for readability something like

```
const CatType mycat = 0x001020ff
```

Which fails with error

```
conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘const CatType’ {aka ‘const std::array<std::byte, 4>’} requested
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `CatType` as a wrapper class instead of a typedef, and define a converting constructor from `int`:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

class CatType {
    private:
        std::array<std::byte, 4> m_arr;

    public:
        CatType(int value) :
            m_arr {
                std::byte((value >> 24) & 255),
                std::byte((value >> 16) & 255),
                std::byte((value >> 8) & 255),
                std::byte(value & 255),
            }
        {

        }

        std::byte& operator [](std::size_t index) {
            return m_arr[index];
        }
        std::byte operator [](std::size_t index) const {
            return m_arr[index];
        }
};
```

If you do not want to create a wrapper class, a [user-defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) (available since C++11) is the closest you can get:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

std::array<std::byte, 4> operator ""_arr(unsigned long long value) {
    return std::array<std::byte, 4> {
        std::byte((value >> 24) & 255),
        std::byte((value >> 16) & 255),
        std::byte((value >> 8) & 255),
        std::byte(value & 255)
    };
}

// Usage:
typedef std::array<std::byte, 4> CatType;
int main() {
    const CatType mycat = 0x001020ff_arr;
    return 0;
}
```